# Sql file extension type

Tags: php

**What is the sql extension type?** 
I want to upload to some folder in my server only .sql files.
 
I know that for txt is text/plain. what is for sql files?

```
 if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != 'THE SQL EXTENSION'){
    echo ' File is not an sql file.';
    exit;
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Despite file extension, the MIME file type should be text/plain as well.

Comment: i tried to put sql, and after the != i wrote text/plain. and there is no procces.

Comment: @Alfabravo as of 2013, `application/sql` is the officially registered media type for SQL code, published shortly after your comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<s>There is no special MIME type for SQL. Just use `application/octet-stream`.</s>

See @Vroo's answer below (`application/sql`). Since RFC6922 was published, this answer is no longer correct.

Comment: As far is I know, SQL files are plain text? Or are there binary formats?

Comment: They are plain text. `application/octet-stream` is somehow considered more of a general purpose type than `text/plain`. Don't ask me why :)

Comment: obviously, there is a special type for that! see @Vroo answer

Comment: @PeterButkovic at the time I wrote this answer (Jan '13) there was no special MIME type for SQL. RFC6922 was published a few months later.

Comment: @glomad The `text` media type is for human-readable text. The `application` media type is for machine-readable data, which may include octets (bytes) that are unintelligible to humans, including binary information such as compiled or executable code, for example.

Answer (score 43):

The official answer according to IANA is `application/sql`. See http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6922

However, since lots of people don't bother to read documentation you might also want to accept `text/sql`, `text/x-sql` and `text/plain`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to check if it's an SQL file simply on the basis of MIME-types. SQL-files are text/plain, as others already pointed out. You would have to perform some checks on the incoming file (like running a regex which check's for SQL commands, or even running a parser/checker, if one is available in PHP), if you want to be sure only SQL files are uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what return $_FILES['userfile']['type']

replace echo ... with echo $_FILES['userfile']['type'];