# Allowing .sql files for a file input field

Tags: html, sql-server, mime-types

I want to limit a file input to only allow XML, SQL and Text files, this is my code so far:

```
<input type="file" name="Input_SQL" id="Input_SQL" value="" accept="text/plain,application/xml,text/x-sql,application/sql,text/sql,application/octet-stream">
```

however, when i browse my computer for files, I am not able to select .sql files.

I have tried the answers listed here [Sql file extension type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268401/sql-file-extension-type) (please see my code).

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Could you tell us about your browser? What is it?

Comment: Hi I was testing with google chrome

Answer (score 3):

Try to specify the extensions instead of the applications:

```
<input type="file" accept=".txt,.sql, (Whatever extensions you want)" />
```