# How to upload .sql type of files in laravel?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

**View code:**

```
<input type="file" name="queryfile" id="queryfile" required>
```

Here I am trying to upload the file with **.sql** extension.

**Controller code:**

```
 public function debinsert1(Request $request)
  {

           $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), 
    array( 
         'devicemodel' => 'exists:addProduct,productId',

        'debfile'                => 'mimes:deb',
         'basefile'                  => 'mimes:deb',
         'versions' => 'unique:MainHaghway',
          **'queryfile'                  => 'mimes:sql',**
    ));

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
else{   
            $temp = new debModel;
 if(Input::hasFile('queryfile')){

            $file=$request->file('queryfile');
            $file->move(public_path().'/downloads',$file-
            >getClientOriginalName());

            $temp->queryfile=$file->getClientOriginalName();


            }
            $temp->save();
```

In this controller code, I am trying to validate with the sql extension and if it succeeds need to insert into db. Validations for other files were working here but, .sql file is not passing with the validation.

**Same view code(ie.,mentioned above):**

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
     <div class = "alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
           @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
           @endforeach
        </ul>
     </div>
  @endif
```

Here ,I am throwing the errors incase of failing validations.

Comment: Try 'mimes:application/sql,application/x-sql'

Comment: Sorry sir,It is not working. The same validation error occurs. ** ie.,The query file must be a file type of:application/sql,application/x-sql**

Comment: Sorry, please change "mimes" to "mimetypes".

Comment: Again the same error occurs

Comment: Check mime type of your file and add it to the rule. If you're using Linux/Mac, use `file --mime-type yourfile.sql` command to check it.

Comment: Sorry,will you please mention it clearly.And then yes i am using linux

Comment: how to check the mime type of my file

Comment: Yes Sir.I get you and on checking with the mime type it echoes as **text/plain**

Comment: Run `file --mime-type yourfile.sql` in Terminal. (Don't forget to change `yourfile.sql` to filename/path of the SQL file.

Comment: **Gem_Admin_Milan_Update_Main.sql: text/plain**-->this is what i get

Comment: OK, it seems like there is [no specific mime for SQL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268401/sql-file-extension-type/29756658). Just add text/plain to the rule. Otherwise, you have to check the extension from the file name manually.

Comment: ok sir.Then how should I check the extension from the file name manually. It  will be really helpful for my further process

Comment: Take a look at [Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: Should I need to write a manual validation for this

Comment: It depends on your requirement and the purpose of the validation. For me, if I only want to store SQL file, I will only add `text/plain,...` to the validation rule (At least, it's not picture/PDF file). To check if the file is valid SQL file, I think it need to try to execute those SQL.

Comment: ok sir!!Thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148750/discussion-between-nishanthi-and-tsctao).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not validate the sql file as laravel **MIME** type [check here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-mimes) but .sql file don't have MIME type that why its not working but you can do this with manual check by use of php function **pathinfo()**.

**Just like this**

```
if(pathinfo($request->queryfile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION)!=='sql'){
    echo 'invalid sql file';
}
```

I thing it will help you.

Comment: Here also it echoes the same thing SIR!!! ie., invalid sql file though I am uploading it with correct extension

Comment: Okay just `print_r($request->queryfile)` and show me what you get.

Comment: ** Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object ( [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => Gem_Admin_Milan_Update_Main.sql [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => application/sql [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 2548 [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [hashName:protected] => [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/php35jCBx [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php35jCBx )**

Comment: this is what it prints

Comment: Okay @nishanthi i just checked with your data now i modified my code just replace `$request->queryfile` to `$request->queryfile->getClientOriginalName()` it will work fine.

Comment: Yes SIR!! amazing it works finally!!..thanks a lot SIR!! but may I know the reason for the change you have made in your coding

Comment: Okay,to get the filetype we need the original filename(text) so i just used `$request->queryfile->getClientOriginalName()` before i was using `$request->queryfile`,which is an object not a filename(text).